# Create random password using java SecureRandom class

Tags: java, security, random, passwords

This is my first experience with java.security.SecureRandom and I'd like someone to critique the follow code to ensure I'm doing this correctly.  The code is supposed to generate a cryptographically secure random password of arbitrary length.  Any input would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class PassGen{

    private static final String VALID_PW_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[]|:;<>?,./";
    private static final int DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 12;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new SecureRandom();


    // main class
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


        // Set password length
        int pwLength;
        if (args.length < 1)
            pwLength = DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
        else
            pwLength = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);


        // generate password
        String pw = "";
        for (int i=0; i<pwLength; i++) {
            int index = (int)(RANDOM.nextDouble()*VALID_PW_CHARS.length());
            pw += VALID_PW_CHARS.substring(index, index+1);
        }

        System.out.println("pw = " + pw);
  }
}
```

Comment: reviews of working code are off topic for SO. There is a seperate site for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  If you have a specific problem in your code, please identify it so that we can help fix it.

Comment: @DavisBroda this code doesn't run if you run it - there is a specific problem here, the OP just asked the question poorly.

Comment: @John This was less about the code itself, and more the way that the question was phrased. There is no actual question here, beyond "does this work". In fact, his question seems to be more about reviewing the algorithms he is using than any particular error. That sore of discussion is not on topic regardless of whether the code actually runs properly. He should either post on Code Review to ask about algorithms/best-practices, or post a question regarding a specific error.

Comment: @DavisBroda well, to be on-topic on CR, the code **must** be working *to the best of OP's knowledge*. Asking "does this code work" is therefore off-topic on Code Review. Please see CR's [help center](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for a refresher - asking "what's the best practice regarding X" is also off-topic on CR.

Comment: @DavisBroda - I guess the jist of my question is whether or not I used the SecureRandom class correctly to generate a cryptographically secure random password.  If this question is more appropriate to codereview.stackexchange.com, then I apologize if I wasted anyone's time.

Answer (score 6):

You can use org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) to generate password using char array and java.security.SecureRandom:

```
public String generatePassword()
{
    return RandomStringUtils.random(DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH, 0, VALID_PW_CHARS.length(), false,
            false, VALID_PW_CHARS.toCharArray(), new SecureRandom());
}
```

In pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings over and over. Also you should look at using `string.charAt(index)` instead of using substring for single chars:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class PassGen{

        private static final String VALID_PW_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[]|:;<>?,./";
        private static final int DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 12;
        private static final Random RANDOM = new SecureRandom();


        // main class
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


                // Set password length
                int pwLength;
                if (args.length < 1)
                        pwLength = DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
                else
                        pwLength = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

                StringBuilder pw = new StringBuilder();


                // generate password
                for (int i=0; i<pwLength; i++) {                        
                        int index = RANDOM.nextInt(VALID_PW_CHARS.length());
                        pw.append(VALID_PW_CHARS.charAt(index)));
                }

                System.out.println("pw = " + pw.toString());
        }
}
```

Also you are generating `double`s and not restricting the index value. I did a mod of the length of the valid chars array to fix this problem.

Comment: I don't think using `RANDOM.nextDouble()` is a good idea here since you'll be getting numbers between 0 and 1 so once you do the mod operation you'll end up picking 'A' every time, leading to passwords like 'AAAAAA'. Instead try doing something like `RANDOM.nextInt(VALID_PW_CHARS.length ())`

Comment: The code as written actually works in that it is giving me completely random strings with various characters.

Comment: @neuronaut - Sorry, I just realized you were referring to John's code

Comment: Using `RANDOM.nextInt(VALID_PW_CHARS.length ())` will give you _slightly_ better randomness because modulus tends to get the lower numbers slightly (alright, very slightly) more often. The [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) documentation discusses it.